# Text detection in images

Tags: python, ios, swift, ocr, coreml

[image]I am using below sample code for text detection in images (not handwritten) using coreml and vision.

https://github.com/DrNeuroSurg/OCRwithVisionAndCoreML-Part2

In this they have used machine learning model which supports only uppercase and numbers. Where as in my project I want upper case, lower case , numbers and few of special characters (like : ,- ).

I do not have any experience in python to do required changes and generate the required .mlmodel file using train data (which again I don't have for my requirement)

Below is the link where it is given how to create .mlmodel
    http://www.neurosurg.de/2017/10/18/part-3-train-your-own-model-using-keras/

does anyone has such .mlmodel? or can somebody help me how to achieve this?

this is the image in which I want to detect text

Comment: If you want to detect various classes of characters then why don't you use some OCR engine like Tesseract(https://github.com/openpaperwork/pyocr)

Comment: you can take a look at this (https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR)

Comment: I have used tesseract but on iOS it is not giving best results on the type of images I am having after doing lot of R & D I have  decided to use coreml for this. Also my images are multiline

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: To _detect_ text you can simply use Vision, which gives you the rectangles that contain text. To _recognize_ text you'll have to figure out what the pixels in those rectangles say. (If you're always trying to scan the exact same type of labels, then you already know where the text rectangles are.)