# Which languages are available for text recognition in Vision framework?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, augmented-reality, coreml, apple-vision

I'm trying to add the option to my app to allow for different languages when using Apple's Vision framework for recognising text.

There seems to be [a function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3152644-supportedrecognitionlanguages) for programmatically returning the supported languages but I'm not sure if I'm calling it correctly because I'm only getting "en-US" back which I'm *fairly*
 sure isn't the only supported language?

Here's what I currently have:

```
// current revision number of Vision
let revision = VNRecognizeTextRequest.currentRevision
var possibleLanguages: Array<String> = []

do {
    possibleLanguages = try VNRecognizeTextRequest.supportedRecognitionLanguages(for: .accurate, 
                                                                            revision: revision)
} catch {
    print("Error getting the supported languages.")
}

print("Possible languages for revision \(revision):\n(possibleLanguages.joined(separator: "\n"))")
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think the language has to be added in the device settings. What device of are running this on? Does that device only have English set in its setting?

Comment: Thanks, I like the thought but I’m on a device that is en-GB only. Just tried adding Russian language to my device and it still shows en-US only.

Comment: @mralexhay Did you find any solution for this. I have to add support for other languages as well.

Comment: @Rashid I still haven't I'm afraid. Let me know if you come across a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### iOS 15

In iOS 15 you can call the following instance method that returns the identifiers of the languages that the request (`VNRecognizeTextRequest`) supports:

```
func supportedRecognitionLanguages() throws -> [String]
```

You can use it this way:

```
print(try! request.supportedRecognitionLanguages())
```

A. Result (if you use `.accurate` recognitionLevel):

```
// ["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant"]
```

B. Result (if you use `.fast` recognitionLevel):

```
// ["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR"]
```

### `recognitionLanguages` property

You can easily tell Vision framework which languages are needed for text recognition using `recognitionLanguages` instance property:

```
var recognitionLanguages: [String] { get set }
```

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3152642-recognitionlanguages): `recognitionLanguages` defines the order in which languages are used during language processing and text recognition.Specify the languages as [ISO language codes](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm).

A real code may look like this:

```
import Vision

let recognizeTextRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest()
recognizeTextRequest.minimumTextHeight = 0.05
recognizeTextRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate

recognizeTextRequest.recognitionLanguages = ["en-US", "fr-FR", "zh-Hans"]
```

##### P.S.

In the beginning of 2020, Vision supported only English.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, this is what I ended up having but I still couldn’t get any other languages to recognise. I went back and watched the WWDC video about it and there’s one quick moment where they say they only support En-US for the first version. I’m sure they’ll add more with iOS14.

Comment: @mralexhay, you're right, it supports only English at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

As of iOS 14, VNRecognizeTextRequestRevision2 supports English, French, Italian, German, Spanish, Portuguese, and Chinese (both Simplified and Traditional) in the `.accurate` recognition level.

```
["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant"]
```

The `.fast` recognition level supports English, French, Italian, German, Spanish, and Portuguese.

```
["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR"]
```

You can check in Playground with this snippet:

```
try VNRecognizeTextRequest.supportedRecognitionLanguages(for: .fast, revision: 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 16 release, this method for checking languages support

`print(try! VNRecognizeTextRequest().supportedRecognitionLanguages())`

returns the following list of languages:

```swift
["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant", "yue-Hans", "yue-Hant", "ko-KR", "ja-JP", "ru-RU", "uk-UA"]
```

Comment: Is this for .accurate only?

Comment: `VNRecognizeTextRequest()` has `recognitionLevel == .accurate` by default, so yes, it is for `.accurate` case.

Comment: in iOS 17 added support of "th-TH", "vi-VT"