# Apple Vision Framework: LCD/LED digit recognition

Tags: swift, machine-learning, coreml, apple-vision, createml

I was developing on an iOS app and everything seemed to work pretty well until I tried capturing images of digital clock, calculators, blood pressure monitors, electronic thermometers, etc.

For some reason [Apple Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) and [VNRecognizeTextRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest) fail to recognize texts on primitive LCD screens like this one:

[image]

You can try capturing numbers with [Apple's sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/reading_phone_numbers_in_real_time) and it will fail. Or you can try any other sample project for the Vision Framework and it will fail to recognize digits as text.

What can I do as an end framework user? Is there a workaround?

Comment: It's quite possible Vision wasn't trained to recognize these kinds of digits. You could try Google's MLKit to see if that works, or perhaps some OCR library such as Tesseract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Train a model...

Train your own `.mlmodel` using up to 10K images containing screens of digital clocks, calculators, blood pressure monitors, etc. For that you can use `Xcode Playground` or `Apple Create ML` app.

Here's a code you can copy and paste into macOS Playground:

```
import Foundation
import CreateML

let trainDir = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/swift/Desktop/Screens/Digits")

// let testDir = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/swift/Desktop/Screens/Test")

var model = try MLImageClassifier(trainingData: .labeledDirectories(at: trainDir), 
                                    parameters: .init(featureExtractor: .scenePrint(revision: nil), 
                                    validation: .none, 
                                 maxIterations: 25, 
                           augmentationOptions: [.blur, .noise, .exposure]))

let evaluation = model.evaluation(on: .labeledDirectories(at: trainDir))

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/swift/Desktop/Screens/Screens.mlmodel")

try model.write(to: url)
```

### Extracting a text from image...

If you want to know how to extract a text from image using Vision framework, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566291/apple-vision-framework-text-extraction-from-image/60692631#60692631).

Answer (score 1):

You can train your own model, for example https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/training_a_create_ml_model_to_classify_flowers